# Ruby sort by hash and value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hashmap

I have data like this:

```
hash_data = [
  {:key1 => 'value4', :sortby => 4},
  {:key1 => 'valuesds6', :sortby => 6},
  {:key1 => 'valuedsd', :sortby => 1},
  {:key1 => 'value2_data_is_here', :sortby => 2}
]
```

I want to sort it to this by the key `sortby`

```
hash_data = [
  {:key1 => 'valuedsd', :sortby => 1},
  {:key1 => 'value2_data_is_here', :sortby => 2},
  {:key1 => 'value4', :sortby => 4},
  {:key1 => 'valuesds6', :sortby => 6}
]
```

I have tried using bubble sort, but is there any inbuilt function in a `Hash` class for such purposes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Enumerable#`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to the rescue:

```
hash_data.sort_by { |hash| hash[:sortby] }
#=> [{:key1=>"valuedsd", :sortby=>1}, {:key1=>"value2_data_is_here", :sortby=>2}, {:key1=>"value4", :sortby=>4}, {:key1=>"valuesds6", :sortby=>6}]
```

If you don't care about initial object, I would suggest using [Array#`sort_by!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-sort_by) to modify inplace - it is more resource-efficient:

```
hash_data.sort_by! { |hash| hash[:sortby] }
```

If you have different types of data as values to `sortby` key, you should first unify the data type and only then perform sorting.

To have array sorted in descending order, use [Enumerable#`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-reverse) (or `reverse!`):

```
hash_data.sort_by {|hash| hash[:sortby] }.reverse
#=> [{:key1=>"valuesds6", :sortby=>6}, {:key1=>"value4", :sortby=>4}, {:key1=>"value2_data_is_here", :sortby=>2}, {:key1=>"valuedsd", :sortby=>1}]
```

Another option for sorting in descending order is the following - note minus sign (credits to **@sagarpandya82**):

```
hash_data.sort_by {|hash| -hash[:sortby] }
```

Comment: giving me this error: `comparison of Float with -0.6 failed`

Comment: @user1735921 with your input data it works. If you have more specific problem - edit your question with real data, because it makes no sense in asking a question ,getting a perfectly valid answer to it and then saying "Hey, on my real data which is absolutely different from OP it does not work" :)

Comment: Hey its sorting the data, but its sorting in ascending order, i want in descending

Comment: @user1735921 in your question you showed ascending order :) but I'll edit for descending

Comment: oh my bad.. can you just add both types

Comment: For descending order `hash_data.sort_by {|hash| -hash[:sortby] }` works too.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 actually a very good note! Will edit the answer